# iOS - Facebook SDK v3.11.1 - results FQL FBGraphObject to javascript parameter (JSON)

Tags: ios, iphone, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I m using Facebook SDK v3.11.1.

In my app, after i open a session, i look for some information view FQL query:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                 parameters:@"SELECT uid, name, can_post FROM user WHERE uid = me()"
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
                              if (error) {
                                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                              } else {

                                  NSString* resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NativeBridge.resultForCallback(mycallback, '%@');", result];

                                  [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:resultString];
                              }
                          }];
}
```

I try to invoke `javaScript` method in my `UIWebView`.
The object `NativeBridge` and the method `resultForCallback` are fine (checked in chrome devTool).

My problem is the parameter `result` which is actually `FBGraphObject`.
I try to send to javaScript parameter like:

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            "can_post" = 1;
            name = "firstName lastName";
            uid = 000000000000000;
        }
    );
}
```

But the javascript refuse to get this parameter.

Any help will be great!

Thanks in advance.